# barring some search strings for my address book

Tags: php, search

I am developing a web page which finds the people's internal phone numbers and organizational e-mail addresses. 
Everything goes fine. After typing at least 3 chars the page lists the matching records.
What I want is to prevent my script some malicious searchings. Everyone in my list has an e-mail address which ends like "somebody@abc.def.gh" If someone types ".gh" it lists all the records at once. I have created an array which has forbidden search strings. But here I am stuck.

```
$forbidden_strings = array(
                            "@abc.def.gh",
                            "abc.def.gh",
                            "bc.def.gh",
                            "c.def.gh"
                            /* goes to the end... */
                          );
```

I have tried to write some but the array's getting larger. Because there are many possibilities. I may miss some of them. And this is not the correct way I guess. There must be a better and cooler and smarter way.

I need some professional help.

Regards.

Comment: Is the issue that people are finding email addresses that they should never see? Or is it that your search is returning too many results for specific queries?

Comment: If people should not be able to list e-mail addresses...why the heck are displaying/allowing it in the first place?

Comment: I do not want people to list all the records at once typing `"@abc.def.gh"` and other possible substrings for example.

Comment: NEVER EVER blacklist! There is an infinite possibility of inputs your user can enter, you should use a regular expression to match the inputs you WANT. Since you know your email addresses will be in the form "abc.def.gh" then use a regex to match only those cases.

Comment: The correct solution is to limit the number of results. For example, after finding 20 results, stop and display a message like "more than 20 results. Show next 20?". Blacklisting queries like this is just silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea! If I divide the e-mail address into two parts I can provide a search for the front-side of it.

```
|name       | email  | domain    |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|John Smith | jsmith | abc.def.gh|
```

Comment: It works! How could I not think that. Sorry stackoverflow and the users!